# Spring Security + JWT | False negative when comparing passwords

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-security, jwt

**This is my third update on this issue:**

Spring's AuthenticationManager performs the .matches() method on my plain String "password" and the encoded "password" String and its returning false every time even though it should return true. I have it configured to use BCrypt but i dont know if im missing something...

**Im adding my SecurityConfig, DaoAuthProvider and Debugger Picture:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private MyUserDetailsService userService;

        @Autowired
        JwtRequestFilter jwtRequestFilter;

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userService)
                    .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/authenticate","/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception{
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```
public class DaoAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {
    private static final String USER_NOT_FOUND_PASSWORD = "userNotFoundPassword";
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    private volatile String userNotFoundEncodedPassword;
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private UserDetailsPasswordService userDetailsPasswordService;

    public DaoAuthenticationProvider() {
        this.setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder());
    }

    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        } else {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            if (!this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, userDetails.getPassword())) {
                this.logger.debug("Failed to authenticate since password does not match stored value");
                throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doAfterPropertiesSet() {
        Assert.notNull(this.userDetailsService, "A UserDetailsService must be set");
    }

    protected final UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        this.prepareTimingAttackProtection();

        try {
            UserDetails loadedUser = this.getUserDetailsService().loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (loadedUser == null) {
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException("UserDetailsService returned null, which is an interface contract violation");
            } else {
                return loadedUser;
            }
        } catch (UsernameNotFoundException var4) {
            this.mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(authentication);
            throw var4;
        } catch (InternalAuthenticationServiceException var5) {
            throw var5;
        } catch (Exception var6) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(var6.getMessage(), var6);
        }
    }

    protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication, UserDetails user) {
        boolean upgradeEncoding = this.userDetailsPasswordService != null && this.passwordEncoder.upgradeEncoding(user.getPassword());
        if (upgradeEncoding) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            String newPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode(presentedPassword);
            user = this.userDetailsPasswordService.updatePassword(user, newPassword);
        }

        return super.createSuccessAuthentication(principal, authentication, user);
    }

    private void prepareTimingAttackProtection() {
        if (this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword == null) {
            this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = this.passwordEncoder.encode("userNotFoundPassword");
        }

    }

    private void mitigateAgainstTimingAttack(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() != null) {
            String presentedPassword = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            this.passwordEncoder.matches(presentedPassword, this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword);
        }

    }

    public void setPasswordEncoder(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        Assert.notNull(passwordEncoder, "passwordEncoder cannot be null");
        this.passwordEncoder = passwordEncoder;
        this.userNotFoundEncodedPassword = null;
    }

    protected PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return this.passwordEncoder;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    protected UserDetailsService getUserDetailsService() {
        return this.userDetailsService;
    }

    public void setUserDetailsPasswordService(UserDetailsPasswordService userDetailsPasswordService) {
        this.userDetailsPasswordService = userDetailsPasswordService;
    }
```

**Debugger picture**

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8F8.png): [What i see in the debugger at the time of the password validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz8F8.png)

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the password section of the spring security documentation, the problem is most likely because you have not prepended your password with what decoder to use.

since you are using `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()`

you can see in the [createDelegatingPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4302a86fad195731f986953d92556a2c755cd8f7/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/factory/PasswordEncoderFactories.java#L66) source code that what you get back is a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`, which basically includes a map, with keys to several password encoders.

If we then look in the source codes first line on the [DelegatingPasswordEncoder#matches](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4302a86fad195731f986953d92556a2c755cd8f7/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java#L252) function we can see that it wants to extract an id from the password to identify which encoder to use.

If you read the [spring security reference on passwords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage), it is very clearly stated how passwords works in spring security, and how a `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` works and `what specific format` to use.

[Password Storage Formats](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe-format)

the password needs to be prepended with the id when stored at rest in the database.

```
{id}encodedPassword
```

Example passwords taken from the documentation.

```
{bcrypt}$2a$10$dXJ3SW6G7P50lGmMkkmwe.20cQQubK3.HZWzG3YB1tlRy.fqvM/BG 
{noop}password 
{pbkdf2}5d923b44a6d129f3ddf3e3c8d29412723dcbde72445e8ef6bf3b508fbf17fa4ed4d6b99ca763d8dc 
{scrypt}$e0801$8bWJaSu2IKSn9Z9kM+TPXfOc/9bdYSrN1oD9qfVThWEwdRTnO7re7Ei+fUZRJ68k9lTyuTeUp4of4g24hHnazw==$OAOec05+bXxvuu/1qZ6NUR+xQYvYv7BeL1QxwRpY5Pc=  
{sha256}97cde38028ad898ebc02e690819fa220e88c62e0699403e94fff291cfffaf8410849f27605abcbc0
```

This format is only needed if you are using the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` because this ensures that you can store passwords in different encoded formats in a database.

If you wish to ignore this format then use the `BCryptPasswordEncoder` directly instead. And `@Autowire` it into the class.

I would suggest that you read the entire section in the spring security reference about passwords, its a 10 minute read and would have saved both you and me time.

Also, i just want to point out, because it would be careless if i didn't at least mention this is that `writing custom security as you have done is bad practice`. [Spring has fully tested and customizable JWT support since 3 years back](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture), so building a custom JWTFilter is not needed, it also has fully built and customizable [DaoAuthenticationProviders](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-daoauthenticationprovider).

Spring security is fully tested, and and used in battle in thousands of applications around the world. Why do you pull in a security library if you do not intend to leverage the functionality in it.

Also, one bug in your code, might compromise your entire application and all its data, make sure you are willing to take that risk before you put it into production.